# How is QTcpServer really listening for connections

Tags: qt, qtcpserver

I am interested in how QTcpServer works behind the scenes regarding threads and blocking. `QTcpServer` has a `listen()` method which returns immediately. If listening started successfully the server will emit the signal `newConnection()`. I'm interested into how is the server listening (is it on the main thread) when the `listen()` method has returned. The usual example of a console application with a QTcpServer is something like this:

```cpp
//main.cpp
int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    QCoreApplication app;
    MyServer server;
    app.exec();
}

//MyServer.cpp
MyServer::MyServer(QObject *parent) : QObject(parent)
{
    this->server = new QTcpServer(this);
    connect(server, SIGNAL(newConnection()), this, SLOT(on_newConnection()));
    if (!server->listen(QHostAddress::Any, 1234))
        //do something in case of error
}
void MyServer::on_newConnection()
{
    QTcpSocket* socket = server->nextPendingConnection();
    //do some communication...
}
```

Is `QTcpServer` dependent upon a `QCoreApplication` (or maybe a `QRunLoop`) existing and running to receive network events. Can it work properly without a `QCoreApplication::exec()` being called?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

I've been drilling through the source code of the `QtCore` and `QtNetwork` modules.

Aperantly, `QTcpServer` can work in two modes: **synchronous** and **asynchronous**.

In **synchronous** mode after calling `listen()` the caller can call `waitForNewConnection()` which is a blocking method (the thread will sleep until someone connects to the listening port). This way `QTcpServer` can work in a thread without an event loop.

In **asynchronous** mode `QTcpServer` will emit the `newConnection()` signal when a new connection was accepted. But to be able to do this there must be an event loop runing. Underlying the `QCoreApplication` are the `QEventLoop` and `QAbstractEventDispatcher` (an abstract class, concrete type is dependent on the OS, for example `QEventDispatcherUNIX`). This event dispatcher can monitor for conditions on sockets (represented by file descriptors). It has a method `registerSocketNotifier(QSocketNotifier*)`. This method is called by the constructor of the `QSocketNotifier` class, which `QTcpServer` creates an instance of every time `listen()` is called. The only system call that is called when the `QTcpServer::listen()` is invoked is, of course, `listen()` which just returns immediately, all the real magic happens when the event loop starts running. The event loop (using the dispatcher) will monitor if there is a certain condition on sockets that have been registered. It calls the **`select()`** system call which receives one or more file descriptors to be monitored (by the kernel) for certain conditions (if there is data to be read, if data can be written, or if an error has occurred). The call can block the thread until the conditions on sockets are met, or it can return after some amount of time passes and the conditions on sockets were not met. I am not sure if Qt is calling `select()` with a waiting time supplied or without (to block indefinitely), I think it is determined in some complicated way and changeable. So when finally the condition on socket has been met, the event dispatcher will notify the `QSocketNotifier` for that socket, which will, in tern, notify the `QTcpServer` who is listening to the socket, which will accept the connection, and emit the `newConnection()` signal.

---

So the `QTcpServer` does not itself call into the event-loop/socket-monitoring system, but it is dependent upon it via the `QSocketNotifier` which it uses for asynchronous recieving of connections.

When synchronous method `waitForNewConnection()` is called it just bypasses all the `QSocketNotifier` stuff and calls `accept()` which blocks the thread until there is an incoming connection.

Comment: Very nice. Now I understand why calling listen before executing the applications event loop in Qt (I use PyQt) did result in not getting a `newConnection` signal. Thanks for digging.

Answer (score 0):

Most of Qt's "behind the scenes" functionality happens inside QCoreApplication's main event loop: signals/slots, timers, etc.
An example would be JavaScript - you bind an event, but event loop is processed by the browser.